# org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange

Tags: apache-camel

I am New to Apache Camel integration with the alfresco activiti, I am getting below error while running below program.

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-Ravi-59907-1467728441130-0-2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1706)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:660)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:471)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:133)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:149)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:301)
        at org.quick.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:32)
    Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Couldn't serialize value '[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route1, node=setProperty1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route1, node=setBody1]]' in variable 'CamelMessageHistory'
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.variable.SerializableType.serialize(SerializableType.java:95)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.variable.SerializableType.setValue(SerializableType.java:69)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableInstanceEntity.setValue(VariableInstanceEntity.java:178)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableInstanceEntity.create(VariableInstanceEntity.java:74)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableInstanceEntity.createAndInsert(VariableInstanceEntity.java:60)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableScopeImpl.createVariableInstance(VariableScopeImpl.java:839)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.createVariableInstance(ExecutionEntity.java:1175)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableScopeImpl.createVariableLocal(VariableScopeImpl.java:752)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableScopeImpl.createVariableLocal(VariableScopeImpl.java:739)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableScopeImpl.setVariable(VariableScopeImpl.java:633)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableScopeImpl.setVariable(VariableScopeImpl.java:590)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.VariableScopeImpl.setVariables(VariableScopeImpl.java:534)
        at org.activiti.camel.CamelBehaviour.execute(CamelBehaviour.java:45)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.ActivityBehaviorInvocation.invoke(ActivityBehaviorInvocation.java:34)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DelegateInvocation.proceed(DelegateInvocation.java:37)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocation(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:25)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskDelegateExpressionActivityBehavior.execute(ServiceTaskDelegateExpressionActivityBehavior.java:98)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:60)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:52)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.java:49)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.java:80)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.java:116)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.java:35)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:453)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:431)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:140)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performDefaultOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:66)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.leave(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:44)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.execute(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:36)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:60)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationProcessStartInitial.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationProcessStartInitial.java:45)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationProcessStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationProcessStart.java:64)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:636)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:629)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.start(ExecutionEntity.java:381)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceCmd.java:110)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceCmd.java:37)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:37)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.RuntimeServiceImpl.startProcessInstanceByKey(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:80)
        at org.activiti.camel.ActivitiProducer.startProcess(ActivitiProducer.java:168)
        at org.activiti.camel.ActivitiProducer.process(ActivitiProducer.java:65)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
        at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:68)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:412)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:380)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:270)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:380)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:238)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:128)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:132)
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessageHistory
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.variable.SerializableType.serialize(SerializableType.java:93)
        ... 104 more
```

**Java Class**

```
package org.quick;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.activiti.engine.RepositoryService;
import org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.activiti.engine.TaskService;
import org.activiti.engine.task.Task;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AppMain {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "application-context.xml");
        RepositoryService repositoryService =
                  (RepositoryService) applicationContext.getBean("repositoryService");
                String deploymentId = repositoryService
                  .createDeployment()
                  .addClasspathResource("helloworld.bpmn")
                  .deploy()
                  .getId();
                System.out.print( "process id is :" +deploymentId);
                CamelContext cxt = (CamelContext) applicationContext.getBean("camelProcess");
                RuntimeService runService= (RuntimeService) applicationContext.getBean("runtimeService");
                ProducerTemplate tpl = cxt.createProducerTemplate(); 
                String instanceId = (String) tpl.requestBody("direct:start", Collections.singletonMap("var1", "hello"));
                String str =  (String) runService.getVariable(instanceId, "var2");
                System.out.print(str);
                System.out.print(str);


                TaskService taskService = (TaskService) applicationContext.getBean("taskService");
                //Retrieving the tasks assigned for the candidate group Register
                List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroup("Register").list();
                for (Task task : tasks) {
                    System.out.println("Following task is available for register group: " + task.getName());

                    // claim it
                    taskService.claim(task.getId(), "rupa");
                }

                // Verify Fozzie can now retrieve the task
                tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee("rupa").list();
                for (Task task : tasks) {
                    System.out.println("Task for roopa: " + task.getName());

                    // Complete the task
                    //taskService.complete(task.getId());
                }

                System.out
                        .println("Number of tasks for roopa: " + taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee("rupa").list().size());
    }

}
```

**XMLs  --  application context**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd ">

    <import resource="classpath:activiti-application-context.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:camel-application-context.xml" />

</beans>


camel-application-context.xml

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd"> 


    <camelContext id="camelProcess" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="myBuilder" /> 
    </camelContext>
    <bean id="myBuilder" class="org.quick.CamelRouteBuilder"/>

    <bean id="camel" class="org.activiti.camel.CamelBehaviour">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.activiti.camel.SimpleContextProvider">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="helloCamelProcess" />
                    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="camelProcess" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the POJO value in variable CamelMessageHistory is not Serializable...

> Couldn't serialize value '[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route1,
>   node=setProperty1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route1,
>   node=setBody1]]' in variable 'CamelMessageHistory' at
>   org.activiti.engine.impl.variable.SerializableType.serialize(SerializableType.java:95)
>   at

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by adding interceptor to camel context:

    `<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <intercept>
            <removeProperty propertyName="CamelMessageHistory" />
        </intercept>
    </camelContext>`

Answer (score 0):

Camel Application Context (camel-application-context.xml):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd"> 

<camelContext id="camelProcess" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="myBuilder" /> 
</camelContext>

<bean id="myBuilder" class="org.quick.CamelRouteBuilder"/>

<bean id="camel" class="org.activiti.camel.CamelBehaviour">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.activiti.camel.SimpleContextProvider">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="helloCamelProcess" />
                <constructor-arg index="1" ref="camelProcess" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```